# Image "Browse file" and "Upload" button are missing problem

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, ce-1.9.2.2, media

I am using magento 1.9.2.2 version, but product image "Browse button" and "Upload button" are missing from admin.

I have checked all media for in Adminhtml and Skin folder all are there. Please help me for this

Comment: Have you tried in the chrome browser? Is the version of flash updated for the browser?

Comment: Yes I have tried in chrome and Mozilla both but notworking

Comment: please upgrade chrome browser Also Allow Flash player. @SharadK